# Warning C4840 en va_start

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017

Hasta ahora no había tenido problemas con el código que adjunto en VS2015.
   VS2017 me muestra el siguiente warning:   **warning C4840: uso no portable de la clase 'ATL::CStringT>>' como argumento de una función variádica** y no adivino por qué. 
   He intentado encerrar *flags* en un *(static_cast(flags))* pero entonces la cosa va a peor. ¿Se te ocurre cual puede ser el problema?

Si te preguntas por que no utilizo un *variadic template* la respuesta es por que tengo mucho código escrito con *va_start* y cambiar rutinas que ya funcionan por procedimientos diferentes me puede llevar a resultados inesperados

```
void Entrada (CString flags, ...)
{
    CString   id;
    va_list   list;

    va_start(list, flags);
    id.FormatV (flags, list);
}

int main()
{
    int nRetCode = 0;

    HMODULE hModule = ::GetModuleHandle(nullptr);


    double   result;
    int      valor = 23;

    Entrada (_T("%s %lf %d"), _T("Texto"), -54.854, valor);

    return nRetCode;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

El motor variádico heredado de C es una bestia problemática, no ofrece seguridad de tipos, es propensa a errores, abre agujeros de seguridad y puede provocar más problemas de los que es capaz de solucionar.

Los argumentos variádicos al estilo C, trabajan con copia de argumentos (¡no se pueden pasar referencias!), y se someten a transformaciones de tipos de manera transparente<sup>1</sup>: se promocionan a `int` los tipos más pequeños que el mismo (incluyendo tipos enumerados y campos de bits)<sup>2</sup>, lo mismo con los tipos más pequeños que `double` y... ¿qué pasa con objetos complejos de C++?.

Pues, depende. Según [el estándar de C++](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n4296.pdf) en el apartado 5.2.2.7 (traducción y resaltado míos):

> #### 5.2.2 Llamadas a función
>
> 7. Cuando no hay parámetro para un argumento proveído, el argumento se pasa de manera que la función receptora puede obtener el valor del argumento invocando `va_arg` [...] Se aplican sobre las expresiones de los argumentos las conversiones estándar lvalue-a-rvalue, array-a-puntero y función-a-puntero. Un argumento cuyo tipo (posiblemente cualificado constante o volátil) sea `std::nullptr_t` será convertido a `void*`. **Tras estas conversiones si el argumento no es de tipo aritmético, enumerado, puntero, puntero a miembro, o clase, el programa está mal formado. Pasar un argumento potencialmente evaluado de tipo clase teniendo un constructor de copia no trivial, un constructor de movimiento no trivial, o un destructor no trivial, es soportado de manera condicional con semánticas dependientes de implementación**.

Dado que los argumentos de funciones variádicas se **copian**, si se usa un tipo cuya construcción o copia puede tener efectos secundarios (es decir: no es un tipo trivial), el compilador puede decidir no dar soporte a dicha operación.

#### ¿Se te ocurre cual puede ser el problema? Claro:

En tu caso, parece que VS2017 sí que da soporte a esta operación, pero dado que otros compiladores pueden decidir no darle soporte, te avisa de que tu código podría no funcionar en otros compiladores (es decir: no es portable).

---

<sup>1</sup>Es decir: sin control del programador y posiblemente sin permiso ni conocimiento del mismo.

<sup>2</sup>Pudiendo causar conversiones *inesperadas* de sin singo a con signo.